# Can not colour in background of 960.gs container

Tags: css, background-color, 960.gs, css-frameworks

I'm using 960.gs (http://960.gs) as a CSS framework for my site and I'm trying to colour in the background of the .container_12 classes rather than my .grid_12 classes for the extra 10px I get on each side, giving the grid a bit of whitespace to breathe.

I looked at the 960.gs example site and he has a background repeating on the y-axis and it seems to expand no matter how large or what is inside the .grid_12 or .grid_16 classes.

When I want to paint the background white (instead of have an image repeat on the y-axis), it appears as though my .grid_12 is floating and therefore .container_12 has no height and thus, no white background.

Here is my relevant HTML

```
<body> 
    <div id="logoContainer" class="container_12"> 
        <div id="logo" class="grid_12"> 
            <h1>Logo</h1> 
        </div> <!-- end #logo --> 
    </div> <!-- end #logoContainer --> 
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    <div id="menuContainer" class="container_12"> 
        <div id="menu" class="grid_12"> 
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" class="selected">Link 1</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </div> <!-- end #menu --> 
    </div> <!-- end #menuContainer --> 
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="contentContainer" class="container_12">
        <div id="content" class="grid_12">
            <p>Content here</p>
        </div> <!-- end #content -->
    </div> <!-- end #contentContainer -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</body>
```

and CSS

```
/* 960.gs */
@import url('reset.css');
@import url('960.css');
@import url('text.css');

#contentContainer
{
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the 960 Grid System!  Cool stuff

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, the `<div class="clear"></div>` need to be after each .grid_, not each .container_